# Django template variable in html

Tags: python, html, css, django

i want to adjust the width of processbar with variable cresource.cpu_avail_percent, how can i add style tag

my code

```
{% for cresource in c_resources %}
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:{{cresource.cpu_avail_percent}}%;">
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

i'm using django 3.2.6

Comment: Templates in Django are rendered on the server-side before being sent to the client. You need to use Ajax or WebSockets to get realtime updates in this case

Comment: thanks @tbhaxor, but how can i use variable for style tag

Comment: Hello @LuanPham check this post https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/22/django-multiple-file-upload-using-ajax.html and this also https://dev.to/shubhamkshatriya25/ajax-file-upload-in-chunks-using-django-with-a-progress-bar-4nhi